# ASP.net - insert record if absent

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, formview

I have a form view which people use to update a record in the database. However initially the record will not exist, and all fields will show their default values. The first time the submit button is clicked, the record should be created in the database. Subsequent submits should update the existing record. The record is identified by it's primary key, which is passed to be page via Request.QueryString.

Does ASP.net provide a simple way of doing this, or do I need to roll my own implementation of the insert/update logic?

Comment: If you have an id in the querystring, don't you already know that it needs to be an update?

Comment: No, because I have two tables in a one-to-one relationship. They share the same key, but a record's pair in the other table will only exist if the user has opted to fill out a particular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET col = @col WHERE id = @id;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.table(id, col) SELECT @id, @col;
END
```

In 2008+ you can also use [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) but I find the syntax quite daunting (and it doesn't isolate you from potential collisions as well as you might think it does).

Comment: I ended up doing this, although I believe it's necessary to enclose in a transaction and use "set transaction isolation level serializable". Otherwise two threads can execute the update statement at the same time and both receive @@rowcount = 0 (if the record wasn't present yet), which result in one thread getting a PK violation when they did the insert.

Answer (score 2):

Read the value and do a GET request to your data source/Repositary. Check whether there is already an Entity / Record exist for this key. If yes call your Update method, else Insert.

Something like this

```
 //check the queystring param value is valid numeric expression 
//before trying to convert

 int itemId=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["itemId"]);

 var item=repo.GetItemById(itemId);
 if(item==null)
 {
   repo.InsertItem(item);
 }
 else
 {
    repo.UpdateItem();
 }
```

Assuming `repo` is an object of your Repositary implementation where you have the Insert and UupdateItem methods present which will do the updation/insertion of data to your persistant  storage.